# Android Spinners Item Selection

Tags: android, spinner

I need a sample logic code...
I have spinner in which I have 3 items ----->Biscuits, Chips, Chocolates,
My Main.xml consists of only only a spinner and search button.

If i select chips from the spinner and click on the search button it should navigate to the chips page.
If I Select Biscuits from the spinner and click on the search button ti should navigate to the biscuits page.

Please help me out in this issue
 Here is the code

```
public class ShoppingActivity extends Activity {
Spinner sp;
Button b;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    //sp.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);

    String[] itemz={"Biscuits","Chips","Chocolates"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,itemz);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(aa);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(sp.equals("Biscuits")){
                Intent i=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Biscuits.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
            if(sp.equals("Chips")){
                Intent j=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Chips.class);
                startActivity(j);

            }
            if(sp.equals("Chocolates")){
                Intent k=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Chocolates.class);
                startActivity(k);

            }
        }
    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

### Your mistake:

You are making mistake by comparting text with the spinner Object which is wrong:

```
if(sp.equals("Biscuits")){
    Intent i=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Biscuits.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

### Solution:

Try below solution to get selected item text and implement solution as per your requirement:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String selectdItemText= mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

if(selectdItemText.equals("Biscuits")){
    Intent i=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Biscuits.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        if(sp.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Biscuits")){
            Intent i=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Biscuits.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
```

Comment: do this for all the if-else cases

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the method `onItemSelected` of your spinner.

```
String itemSelected = "";

sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        itemSelected =(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(itemSelected.equals("Biscuits")){
            Intent i=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Biscuits.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
        if(itemSelected.equals("Chips")){
            Intent j=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Chips.class);
            startActivity(j);

        }
        if(itemSelected.equals("Chocolates")){
            Intent k=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Chocolates.class);
            startActivity(k);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @ZouZou... Thank you for the reply..!!! Actually I'm new to android development. Can you edit above code and send..!!! Don't think otherwise... I'm unable to understand where to place it..!!!

Comment: Can you edit the code which I sent you with the code you replied?? Because I'm new to Android and I'm unable to place it at the appropriate location... Thanks In Advance @ZouZou

Answer (score 0):

i have edited your code

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(sp.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Biscuits")){
            Intent i=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Biscuits.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
        if(sp.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Chips")){
            Intent j=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Chips.class);
            startActivity(j);

        }
        if(sp.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Chocolates")){
            Intent k=new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, Chocolates.class);
            startActivity(k);

        }
    }
});
```